# Setup containers

Tags: server, lxd, container

I have ubuntu 17.10 and i'm trying to setup containers that people can ssh into from outside my network. I tried installing LXD containers and had a friend try to ssh into it but it says connection refused. I'm fine with switching software if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Have you set up port forwarding anything like that? Configured the SSH server to accept connections etc etc?

Comment: A few things you should specify: (a) How is the network bridge set up? Are containers assigned IP addresses that are reachable from other computers *inside* your network? (b) How is your network connected to the internet? Do you have a dedicated router, or is your server connected to it directly? Whichever machine serves as router, does it have port-forwarding rules to your LXD hosts?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a gateway/jump script to allow incoming ssh connections to be routed to specific LXD containers: https://github.com/Dweller/lxd-ssh-gateway

From the project's README:

> Forward incoming ssh connections for a single user into containers
>
> Very simple example which demonstrates the concept..
>
> My recomendation for the LXD host configuration for
> /etc/ssh/sshd_config are:-
>
> ```
> PasswordAuthentication no
> PermitUserEnvironment yes
> ```
>
> Then add a 'sandbox' user on your Linux server...
>
> Then install the ~sandbox/bin/gw, ~sandbox/etc/notice and a
> ~sandbox/.ssh/authorised_keys Limitation with this method is a key can
> only be used to forward to a single container. See the
> authorized_keys.example for the command="$HOME/bin/gw ssh-rsa syntax.
>
> Make sure the permissions/ownership are correct..
>
> ```
> #chown -R sandbox:sandbow ~sandbow
> #chmod -R g-rewx,o-rwx ~ssandbox/bin
> ```
>
> The containers I've been building are Ubuntu 20.10 they don't need to
> run ssh to work nor do they need networking.
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
> #lxc launch ubuntu:20.10 container-X
> ```
>
> Assuming thats all installed and working some examples of usage:-
>
> ```
> ssh -i ~/.ssh/priv.key sandbox@<host address/ip>
> sftp -i ~/.ssh/priv.key sandbox@<host address/ip>
> scp -i ~/.ssh/priv.key /etc/hosts sandbox@<host address/ip>:
> ```